# How to modify Canon's printer driver for linux?

Tags: drivers, printing, display-resolution, canon

Ubuntu 18.04.5, Canon Pixma TS6220 printer.
The driver file is Canon_Pixma_TS6200.ppd.  It works fine but only offers 600dpi print quality.  I have looked at the various ppd files and used gedit to change the resolution from 600 to 300 and 1200, but the printer still prints at 600 dpi.  The printer.conf file lists "Option print quality 3".  Changing this number has no affect on the printout, either.  I would like to modify the files to provide choices of 300/600/1200 (or draft/normal/high).  Has anyone tried this?  TIA, A4Skyhawk

Comment: I did.  They flat out state that they do not provide any support for this (linux) driver, and that since it is open source, modifications should be handled by those in the open community.  Not very helpful, right?

Comment: Egad, that's awful. Crossing them off my list of potential hardware manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution 1200 is not offered in the PPD. That implies the printer is not natively capable of doing it. If you want something like draft/normal/high to be on offer, try [driverless printing.](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting)